Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem in ASP.NET Core
In ASP.NET MVC 5 I often invalidated request cache items with code like this in a controller
Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/Client/Photo/1");

The RemoveOutputCacheItem option appears to be removed in ASP.NET Core. What is the alternative?

I worked this out, it is a multi step process.
Firstly you need to create your own OutputCache Policy, something like this
public class OutputCacheWithAuthPolicy : IOutputCachePolicy
{
    public static readonly OutputCacheWithAuthPolicy Instance = new();
    private OutputCacheWithAuthPolicy() { }

    ValueTask IOutputCachePolicy.CacheRequestAsync(OutputCacheContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var attemptOutputCaching = AttemptOutputCaching(context);
        context.EnableOutputCaching = true;
        context.AllowCacheLookup = attemptOutputCaching;
        context.AllowCacheStorage = attemptOutputCaching;
        context.AllowLocking = true;

        var id = context.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["id"];
        if (id != null)
            context.Tags.Add($"Client_{id}");

        // Vary by any query by default
        context.CacheVaryByRules.QueryKeys = "*";
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }
    private static bool AttemptOutputCaching(OutputCacheContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (!HttpMethods.IsGet(request.Method) && !HttpMethods.IsHead(request.Method))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    public ValueTask ServeFromCacheAsync(OutputCacheContext context, CancellationToken cancellation) => ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    public ValueTask ServeResponseAsync(OutputCacheContext context, CancellationToken cancellation) => ValueTask.CompletedTask;
}

The important bit is where the tag with the ID is being added. This will be required to evict from the cache later on.
In your Program.cs you will need to configure the policy like this
builder.Services.AddOutputCache(options =>
{
    options.AddBasePolicy(builder => builder.Cache());
    options.AddPolicy("OutputCacheWithAuthPolicy", OutputCacheWithAuthPolicy.Instance);
})
....
app.UseOutputCache();

In my controller I have code something like this.
public ClientController: Controller
{
  public ClientController(IOutputCacheStore outputCache) 
  {
    _outputCache = outputCache;
  }

  private IOutputCacheStore _outputCache;

  [OutputCache(VaryByQueryKeys = ["id"], Duration = 86400, PolicyName = "OutputCacheWithAuthPolicy")]
  public IActionResult ProfilePic(int id)
  {
    var profilePic = GetPic();
    return File(profilePic, "image/png");
  }

  public async Task<IActionResult> EvictPic(int id, CancellationToken token)
  {
        await _outputCache.EvictByTagAsync($"Client_{id}", token);
        ....
  }
}

You will see the EvictPic action which forcibly evicts it from the cache

If you use IMemoryCache, you can delete the cache by using the _cache.Remove(key)method.
private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

public CustomCacheService(IMemoryCache cache)
{
    _cache = cache;
}

public void RemoveCacheItem(string key)
{
    _cache.Remove(key);
}

If you want to control the cache items of a specific path from the output cache, you can apply the ResponseCacheAttribute attribute on the controller method or controller class and disable the cache by setting NoStore = true like:[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None)] .

I have tried this but I am unable to find the entry in the MemoryCache. It has many other entries, and the ResponseCache is working I can confirm, but just can't see the entries to remove them.
